# Which Iron Man comic follows Invincible Iron Man?

Tags: marvel, suggested-order, iron-man

I've been casually following the *Invincible Iron Man* comic by Matt Fraction and Salvador Larroca.  I've been picking up the hard cover collected editions via Amazon every 6 months as they're released.  The last one was [Vol 11: The Future](http://amzn.com/0785165215), which [Comicvine states](http://www.comicvine.com/reviews/invincible-iron-man-527/1900-1111/) contains the last issue for these creators.  Based on Amazon searches, there's no Vol 12 coming, so it seems that volume of *Invincible Iron Man* ended there as well.

Since I haven't closely followed comic books during this time, I don't know where to go from here.  What Iron Man book(s) follow the ending of *Invincible Iron Man*?

Comment: Maybe he rusted :p

Comment: I know that he appeared with the Guardians of the Galaxy briefly, while he was still in his Red/Gold suit. Since issue 527 ends with him flying off into space, would it be fair to say that story arc from GotG comes in between Fraction and Gillen's series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The series that follows is [Iron Man](http://www.comicvine.com/iron-man/4050-53725/) by Kieron Gillen and Greg Land which launched as part of Marvel NOW!

The first collection which contains 1-5 is called "[Believe](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0785168338)"

From Comic Vine's page on the new volume:

> The series is a continuation from The Invincible Iron Man vol. 5 (2008).

Also, the release dates seem to support this: [#1](http://www.comicvine.com/iron-man-1-believe-1-of-5-demons-and-genies/4000-365759/) of this volume was out November 7th 2012 and [#527](http://www.comicvine.com/the-invincible-iron-man-527-the-future-finale-the-/4000-363158/) of *Invincible* out a couple of weeks earlier on October 24th.

Additionally [this review](http://www.comicvine.com/reviews/iron-man-1/1900-1144/) (spoilers most likely within) of #1 of the new volume  says:

> For a Marvel NOW! issue, it does have some elements of a 'new jumping
>   on point' but also feels close enough to Matt Fraction and Salvador
>   Larroca's run. Tony is still Tony and other bits like Resilent and
>   Pepper Potts are still here. This could have easily been a
>   continuation of INVINCIBLE IRON MAN so fans should be pleased.

Comment: Does this pick up, story-wise, where *Invincible Iron Man* ended?

Comment: @Keen I'm not 100% sure, I trade wait for the paperbacks, so I've only just read v9 "Demon". However, Comic Vine says "The series is a continuation from The Invincible Iron Man vol. 5 (2008)" so I assume so. Also, Comic Vine has #1 out November 7th 2012 and #527 of Invincible out a couple of weeks earlier on October 24th.

Comment: Sounds good to me, I've ordered the soon-to-be-released collected edition of that.